# What commission is charged from Apple Store and Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play, app-store

I have an app which is free for end-users. But the app contains payment mechanism in it. It uses third party integrations for payments.The payment is used for purchasing or different plans so to provide different features inside the app to user depending on the plan user has selected. Will App Store or google store will charge any commission for this payment? If yes, then what percentage?

Another question is that for these payment, I have to add Apple Pay and google pay also?

Please someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you sell **digital** products within your app you are required to use In App Purchases mechanisms (directly or through your 3rd party).

The fees is 30% by default on both stores but you can request a discount to 15% under 1M$ revenue.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/112622
https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2020/11/apple-announces-app-store-small-business-program/

Note than on iOS you are not allowed to add a link to your website where the user could subscribe (even if it opens outside the app),  not sure on Android.